# how to implement Cron jobs(shedulded tasks) for a servlet in Appengine Application

Tags: google-app-engine

I start developing Google Appengine Java Application..for that I am using Servlet, jsp and EClipse helios IDE.

In my Application, I want to create a servlet, that will execute for Particular time interval(every 5 minutes) and the the get values are stored in datastore.....

How to do this...Also i go through about Scheduling tasks [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html).But I didn't understand how to implement in my project using Eclipse....

Please help me.....

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a servlet that will handle requests to the URL you specify in your [cron config](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html#About_cron_xml).  Your `cron.xml` gets saved in the same location as your `appengine-web.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

cron job in AppEngine uses http GET, so just any servlet that handles doGet() will suffice.

suppose your servlet is mapped to /mytask in web.xml, then in cron.xml,

```
<cron>
    <url>/mytask</url>
    <description>describe your task here</description>
    <schedule>every 1 minutes</schedule>
</cron>
```

this instructs appengine to issue a httpGet at URL /mytask every minute.